# Video to Live Wallpaper that survives a restart

Tags: video, live-wallpaper

I have an MP4 that I want as my live wallpaper. I can set it, but only through an app. The app does not, of course - automatically at startup - select the file, then set it as a live wallpaper. As I understand it, Android, unlike iOS, does not support live wallpapers WITHOUT an app.

Is there a way to create a live wallpaper that will remain stable in my system?

- What I tried: I installed - and uninstalled - a host of video-to-wallpaper apps, in the hope that one might have a start-up option in the settings. None did.
- I have Google wallpapers installed. In it, I went to "live wallpapers", one of the things there was the video-to-live-wallpaper app, I selected it, it gave me the MP3, and I set it as the live wallpaper. Restarted the phone - gone.
- I've set the live wallpaper in the app, in the phone's launcher settings, and in the Android system settings, all to no avail.

Every single time I start the phone I have to open the app, find the MP4, and set it as the live wallpaper - again.

Alternatively: can that MP4 be converted to a live wallpaper format that does NOT require some outside app to be running in the background supporting it?

Phone running Android 12.